# How to find out Hard disk first & last sector ID's?

Tags: linux, hard-disk

Is that possible to find Hard disk sector's ID? If we can, how to find out Hard disk 1st & last sector ID's in windows & LINUX?

As I tried to Google it, I found only hard disk sector size. If any one know about this please update.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux you can get the number of sectors on disk with `fdisk`:

```
mtak@frisbee:~/test$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 256.1 GB, 256060514304 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 31130 cylinders, total 500118192 sectors
[output omitted]
```

On the second line you see the total number of sectors.

Comment: thanks for your update mtak.. But I was looking each sector ID no.s if its possible as we are working on some software development which needs each sectors ID's.

Comment: So the first sector would be sector 0 and the last sector would be (total number of sectors-1)?